# Meaning of 'That old rocking chair's going to get me'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, expressions, lyrics

In the Joni Mitchell song [Stormy Weather](http://www.songmeanings.net/songs/view/3530822107859069849/), there's this line:

> That old rocking chair's going to get me

What does that mean? I suppose *that old rocking chair* is a symbol of something, but what? Death? Something else?

Comment: Svish- Unfortunately interpretation of song lyrics is off-topic on ELU.

Comment: Well, I wasn't really after interpretation of the lyrics. Just the 'old rocking chair' part, if it was a well-known english expression or something, which it sometimes is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long before [Stormy Weather](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stormy_Weather_%28song%29) was “the Joni Mitchell song [Stormy Weather](http://www.songmeanings.net/songs/view/3530822107859069849/)” it was a signature tune for [Lena Horne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lena_Horne%3a_The_Lady_and_Her_Music) and was recorded by [numerous other singers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stormy_Weather_%28song%29#Other_versions).

“That old rocking chair's going to get me” expresses the idea that grief will reduce the singer to an old lady at the end of her days, just rocking back and forth in an old rocking chair and contemplating her sorrows.

Comment: Best of all, here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIIGahCEqP8