# A song by Dr. Dre

Tags: meaning, terminology

Consider the following text:

Bitches ain't shit but hoes and tricks.
Lick on these nuts and suck the dick. 
Get the fuck out after you're done. 
*And I hope in my ride to make a quick run.*

I am wondering about the meaning of the very last sentence, could somebody clarify what is meant by this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpretation of song lyrics. FWIW I think *ride* in "gansta rap" terminology usually means "flashy car".

Comment: @FumbleFingers the song is written in English.

Comment: @jlovegren: That's debatable! :) And the fact that OP has introduced a significant typo doesn't exactly make the question a better fit.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't mind rap lyrics on the site. Some like English learners like Maureen Dowd, some like Dr. Dre. *honni soit qui mal y pense*

Comment: @jlovegren: Well, you certainly live up to that principle! :) I don't want to get too bogged down in my opinions on Dr Dre and his odious attitude to women, but I kinda doubt he's wistfully singing about the fact that his "work commitments" don't leave him enough time to *spend tender moments with his beloved wife.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: in fact I didn't realize that this is a typo (the lyrics are from the internet), and this was the main reason why it did not make sense to me. Come on brother, this is good stuff; otherwise you act according to another song by Dre (among others): "you'll probably get mad like a bitch is supposed to" (just joking). Anyway, I HOP IN MY RIDE TO MAKE A QUICK RUN.

Comment: @Karl: To a considerable extent, we're free to both make up our own rules and interpret them as we see fit, here on ELU. But there are an awful lot of [closed questions about song lyrics](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96361/). I suspect most users feel the same way I do about them. [Here's a relevant discussion on meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/995/), if you're interested.

Comment: I don't mind gangsta rap. In fact I've been listening to it for three decades now. Coincidentally, *that* is the reason I am closing it as gen ref. *Ride* is in every dictionary by now. And that you didn't catch the typo only blows your cover as someone who hasn't so much as listened to the song once. Come on brother, this is good stuff!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: this is clear. @ Reg: I just find the text amusing, I don't listen to it. Well "ride" and "quick run" are not in my dictionary

Comment: (hand waving) Just so I don't come across as a complete "musical luddite" - I do quite like [The Grey Album](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Grey_Album). (But I suppose that's probably more MOR than rap, let alone *gangsta rap!* :)

Comment: It's not "gangsta rap", it is traditional afro american music. maybe just don't like having fun, I ain't surprised.

Comment: @FumbleFingers though I find the song lyrics offensive, I still try to write a tactful answer.  I've noted that some of our more popular questions may contain offensive comment, so I assume that we look past whether or not a question contains offensive language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line should be written *And I hop in my ride to make a quick run.* To hop in one's ride means to get into personal car. To make a run means to transport illicit cargo. The author in this case is lamenting that as a drug runner he lacks time to spend tender moments with his beloved wife.